# How does git parse tree objects contents?

Tags: object, github, tree

I know that git stores trees as objects. But how does it extract the information from that object when needed? How does it parse that file to get the contents?

I mean how does git have access to pointers(tree, commits, blobs) all the time?

Comment: What do you mean by this? When git isn't running, it's not in memory and all of the pointers and such disappear. The data is serialized. Are you asking about the format git uses to serialize repository information and/or internal data structures when it's not executing?

Comment: I meant that git tree object is stored in text format, so to get contents of that tree; will it parse it as a text file ? or am I taking this the wrong way?